# How to convert Pascal Triangle Generator from 2-D to 1-D arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a question.

I've made a Pascal Triangle Generator program in Java using 2-D arrays and it was generally simple.
However, I can't seem to figure out how to program the same thing using only a 1-D array.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I will try to insert code once when I can, but I'm asking this in a general sense; what should you think about when converting 2-D arrays to 1-D array?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post your code, and what you've tried. Should be easy to do with `/` and the `%` operator applied to your original array dimensions.

Comment: One thing for sure, 1D array code will be less readable

Comment: Java does not know 2D arrays, only 1D arrays containing 1D arrays so not much to do there ;-).

Answer (score 1):

All the answers posted thus far have given cookie-cutter solutions to turning a 2D array into a 1D array. As far as I can tell, storing a Pascal's triangle in a statically dimensioned 2D array is pretty inefficient since around half the entries are unused.

The main issue is that the triangle is ... well, triangular, whereas a rectangular 2D matrix is relatively easy to unroll.

However, a triangle is still quite simple to unroll. You just need to figure out where each offset is. Consider storing your pascal's triangle as follows in a 1-D array:

1,1,1,1,2,1,1,3,3,1

Consider the ith row in the Pascal's triangle. Its first entry is in the (1+2+...+i-1)th entry in the 1-dimensional array. This is a simple arithmetic progression sum which evaluates to (i-1)(i)/2. So, write some functions like:

```
int getArrayOffset(int row, int offset) {
  // assert(row>0);
  return (row*(row-1))/2 + offset - 1;
}

int calculateEntry(int row, int offset, int[] triangle) {
  triangle[getArrayOffset(row,offset)] = triangle[getArrayOffset(row-1,offset-1)]+triangle[getArrayOffset(row-1,offset)];
}

void calculatePascal(int n) {
  int [] triangle = new int[getArrayOffset(n+1,1)];
  for (int row=1; row <=n; row++) {
    triangle[getArrayOffset(row,1)]=1;
    triangle[getArrayOffset(row,row)]=1;
    for (int offset=2; offset < row; offset++) {
       calculateEntry(row,offset,triangle);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure until I see your code, but generally -
you can try different addressing mode in your code.

2D case: array is mxn... Addressing goes [i,j]

same data can be stored in 1D, row after another / column wise. Lets say it was row wise. Then the addressing mode will be -[i*(n) + j]
where i=0..m & j=0..n

Cheers,

Rishikesh

Answer (score 0):

You just have to replace all accesse operation to your array from `data[x][y]` to `data[x+y*width]` or `data[x*height+y]`.
If you have only given the index of a field and you want to calculate the coordinates that would be

```
x=index%width;
y=index/width; //be sure to use integer division here
```

or

```
x=index/width; //be sure to use integer division here
y=index%width;
```

You can find out more about pairing functions here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_pairing_function